# Do Julian day number handle timezone offset?

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I am currently working on some FX rate modeling. I decided to use the dataset from UBC: http://fx.sauder.ubc.ca/data.html

But I find that I have a problem about the timezone. The dataset is daily basis, with a Julian Day Number, does this number handle timezone shift? Or does it use GMT+0 or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have clicked the links on that page you would have ended up [here](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php). Here is the relevant quote

> Julian dates (abbreviated JD) are simply a continuous count of days
>   and fractions since noon Universal Time on January 1, 4713 BCE (on the
>   Julian calendar)

Another [link](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/UT.php) in that page defines what Universal Time is:

> The times of various events, particularly astronomical and weather
>   phenomena, are often given in "Universal Time" (abbreviated UT) which
>   is sometimes referred to, now colloquially, as "Greenwich Mean Time"
>   (abbreviated GMT). The two terms are often used loosely to refer to
>   time kept on the Greenwich meridian (longitude zero), five hours ahead
>   of Eastern Standard Time. Times given in UT are almost always given in
>   terms of a 24-hour clock. Thus, 14:42 (often written simply 1442) is
>   2:42 p.m., and 21:17 (2117) is 9:17 p.m. Sometimes a Z is appended to
>   a time to indicate UT, as in 0935Z.

So the answer is yes. Julian Day uses GMT+0.